# Number of the positive (> 0) values in each row of a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, sum

Considering A = a 100 by 5 matrix of random integers between -100 and 100, I would like to find B = the number of the positive (>= 0) values in each row of A using sum (no loops).

`B=sum(rint(:)>0)` does not seem right as it only gives me the total number of positive values of the whole matrix.

How do I get the values for each row?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `B=sum(rint>0)` to get the sum of the columns, and `B=sum(rint>0,2)` to get the ones of the row. Sum accepts a second argument to define the dimension on which you are summing.